# generate wallets in exchanges like binance?

Tags: wallet, exchanges, bip32-hd-wallets, wallet-security, binance

I'm a Laravel developer and I have a project in exchanges field. I need to know how can I generate deposit address for per coin belongs to per user.
I want to do this in secure way and I need to best suggestions.
Is HD wallets best choice for this situation? Do all coins have HD wallets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/hd-protocol

Definition

The Hierarchical Deterministic (HD) key creation and transfer protocol (BIP32), which allows creating child keys from parent keys in a hierarchy. Wallets using the HD protocol are called HD wallets

So this allows you to create lots of addresses just from a Master Key

`Are they secure?`

As far as you don't leak your mnemonic, all your addresses are safe

`Do all coins have HD wallets?`

HD wallets provides you a way of managing the addresses more efficiently and easily. So coins don't have wallets, addresses managed by those wallet can hold coins

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thank you for your response.As you said: "So coins don't have wallets" I confused about addresses for alt coins or Eth coin or ripple and others. Do I need to generate address to get coins and alt coins, right? or you mean bitcoin address can hold and receive all coins? I mean assume a person wants to send me ETH or others, and I have to give my ETH address,right?

Comment: Yes, different types of coins have different addresses and those addresses can only hold the supported coins. So ETH address can only hold ETH and related alt coin while BTC address can only hold BTC and related alt coins and so on...

Comment: Great. So I think all coins don't have HD wallets and this concept is only for BTC. Am I right?

Comment: This line is not true 'So I think all coins don't have HD wallets'. HD wallets just provide you the addresses which are related to certain blockchain and that addresses can store the coins of only that blockchain only. So for example a typical BTC address looks like : 3PbJsixkjmjzsjCpi4xAYxxaL5NnxrbF9B. It can hold any coins which use btc technology. LIkewise a typical ETH address looks like : 0xb46a3Cc3A5a247A831484e1D6aC6d8Fd25B804eE. It can hold any coins using ETH technology. So HD wallets can be used to create addresses of any blockchain and are not limited to just BTC

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any useful links for these concepts and any tutorials to develop HD wallets?

Comment: And I have a question about BIP. according this link https://github.com/bitcoin/bips we have many BIP. For know there are many many Bips and the latest is bip-0342, these are updated version of HD wallets or per BIP is totally different and belongs to others improvements and issues?

Comment: (https://iancoleman.io/bip39/), (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70017/can-someone-explain-the-meaning-of-derivation-path-in-wallet-in-plain-english-s), The first link will cover everything in terms of concepts and all but hd wallet creation depends on programming language as well. So its hard to provide a link for the same reason.

Comment: BIP is Bitcoin Improvement Proposal, so it provides with different proposals to improve bitcoin. BIP32 shows how to implement HD wallets and so that is important for your work and BIP44 as well. So BIP is overall improvements of Bitcoin and HD wallets are part of those